# loading image dyanmically into tableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Is there a better way to load images dynamically into the tableviewcell for different rows other than using the if statements? What if I have a lot of cells. does that mean I would have to write a lot of if statements? Also is there a way to retrieve an image from core data and use it as a image for tableview cell? thanks in advance.

```
- (UIImage *)imageForMagnitude:(CGFloat)magnitude { 
if (magnitude >= 5.0) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.0.png"];
}
if (magnitude >= 4.0) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.0.png"];
}
if (magnitude >= 3.0) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.0.png"];
}
if (magnitude >= 2.0) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.0.png"];
}
return nil;
```

}

edit: what if it isn't about magnitude? for example a list of products or like the app store on the iphones. how did they manage to generate different images for the different apps on the table? are they using a table or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does each UITableViewCell have it's own magnitude? If no then no, you don't need to have a different if statement for each cell. Plus where is that function being called? Why would you want to use core data to store images as BLOBs? I think UIImage has caching going on so you'll probably want to take advantage of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round down the magnitude using the `floorf` function from `<math.h>`

Then use the `MIN` and `MAX` macros to protect the real value from going above 5 or below 2.

```
int realMagnitude = (int) MAX(MIN(floorf(magnitude), 5.0f), 2.0f);
return [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.0.png", realMagnitude]];
```

**Update:** I think this is what you're looking for: in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, use the provided `NSIndexPath` to fetch the relevant image:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: what if it isn't magnitude? like a list of products with different pictures?

Comment: @Hong Yi: I don't understand.

Comment: the magnitude code was an example of how you could have different images on a UITableViewCell. Is there a simpler way to do that dynamically? like UIImage imageNamed: "%@.jpg", indexPath.row kind of code? What i mentioned can't work because of too many arguments. So I was thinking maybe there was a better way. Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: @Hong Yi: Where are there too many arguments? I don't understand.

Comment: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"%@.jpg", indexPath.row]. I keep getting too many arguments, expected 1 have 2. What I was trying to do was to name the pictures in ascending number so that it would display all the images.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm maybe a switch statement. Or you could just round the magnitude off and then..

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.0.png", newMagnitude];
```